# how to use mono in my cross platform project

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mono, cross-platform

I've been searching solutions for my enterprise apps, at least 3 platforms need to be supported, which are iOS, Android and Window Phone. After a whole day's search, I finally set my eyes on 2 promising cross platform solutions, one is monocross and the other phonegap.
monocross seems to use c# and .net at all, is it possible to access native libraries and languages? I read somewhere it's compiled directly into binaries that can execute on target platforms.
And about phonegap, it uses webviews on each platform to provide the capabilities of presenting user interfaces to final users. As it's implemented via interpreted language and high level apis, the performance may not meet our needs.
Finally, we(my team) decide to give it a try with mono, the architecture is illustrated as bellow:

+++++++++++++++++++++representation layer++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[monotouch,monodroid,silverlight]or [native gui calls] or [html5/js/css]

+++++++++++++representation controller/business logic layer+++++++++++++++
[                                 mono/c#                       ] 

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++server side+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[                                 the cloud                     ]

I want to use mono/c# to write some common purpose business logic and data structures, and when it comes to some common platform features, like storage service, notifications, I'd like to wrap them up on each platform and expose uniform apis for c#(business logic layer) to use. As to the representation layer, we decide to choose from the 3 optional solutions listed above.

To make this happening, first I have to figure out if it is possible to call native frameworks.
So, my questions are:
1, How does mono work, I mean, are the c# codes compiled into binaries that can be executed directly on iOS, Android and Windows Phone? 
2, Is there a mechanism to make native invocations? Like in cocos2d-x, I can call java methods via JNI, and in iOS, c++ can call oc directly. Can I call cocoa touch stuffs in mono with c#?
3, Is it possible to manage all these stuffs in one single project, and how to build them?
4, Are there any better solutions?

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why Xamarin does not land on the first page of your search result,

http://xamarin.com/features

But that's what the Mono guys created for the C# developers that want to target mobile platforms. MonoTouch and Mono for Android are there each featuring a common library base with Microsoft .NET, and also platform specific bindings.

Your non-UI code should be able to be used in portable libraries and share among them. Microsoft's portable library is Windows specific, and right now I am not sure how much Mono guys can embrace that, but even if PCL fails, you can create multiple platform specific projects based on the same copy of source files (which I did in #SNMP). The remaining task is to develop platform specific UI for Windows Phone, iOS, and Android.

There are tons of articles showing the features,

http://docs.xamarin.com/

and also many successful apps

http://xamarin.com/apps

The best way to learn a product is to try it out (for free in Xamarin's case). This also applies to MonoCross (which is a framework built upon Mono).

I am not familiar with PhoneGap, so you need someone's advice on that.

Comment: Thanks Lex, I think you have pointed out the right way for me, as a matter of fact, I did searched Xamarin, but I get confused and think monocross and Xamarin are the same thing.

Comment: Xamarin should be considered as an infrastructure vendor in this case, who built CLR for non-Microsoft platforms. MonoCross seems to be a very promising framework upon Xamarin's offer, while Xamarin itself launched Xamarin.Mobile (http://xamarin.com/mobileapi)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is not a complete answer - but I do hope it answers at least part of your question

---

I encountered a similar problem when I started cross-platform dev using the Mono products 18 months ago.

The approach I've built since is called MvvmCross - it forked off of MonoCross a long time ago - now shares no code with it (but maybe we'll team up again one day!).

The approach uses PCLs to share code. This is not entirely painless, but is easy after you've done a few setup steps - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html

You can learn more about this approach on this video: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/mvvmcross-video-presentation-xaminar.html

Comment: Thank you for the constructive information, before the project start, I might have chance to do much homework on all these options